# How can I load an image from a Drupal field to UIImageView?

Tags: mysql, ios, drupal, uiimageview

I'm building an app for my Drupal based website. I currently have my iOS application pulling data from the MySQL database (e.g. Article titles and descriptions). Does anyone know what sort of code I would use to display an article's corresponding image (uploaded via a Drupal field) in an UIImageView?

Here's a quick snippet of the code I'm using to pull text from my Drupal site.

**DoctorsViewController.h**

```
@interface DoctorsViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITableView *DoctorsTableView;

    NSArray *Doctors;
    NSMutableData *data;

}
```

**DoctorsViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.


[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"MY URL HERE"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{
    [data appendData:theData];

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    Doctors = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
    [DoctorsTableView reloadData];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The download could not complete - please make sure that you're connected to 3G or Wi-Fi." delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorView show];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;


}
- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *)tableview

{
    return 1;

}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [Doctors count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *DoctorsTableIdentifier = @"DoctorsCell";

    DoctorsCell *cell = (DoctorsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DoctorsTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DoctorsCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    } 

    cell.firstnameLabel.text = [[Doctors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"node_title"];

    cell.descriptionLabel.text = [[Doctors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Opening Paragraph"];


    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't as straightforward as it sounds - Drupal stores its field data in a very specific way, and URIs to the images are addressed with a schema rather than having a relative or absolute path (e.g. public://path/to/image.jpg as opposed to /sites/default/files/path/to/image.jpg)

You can get the image URIs for a node straight from the DB like this (assuming your article type uses the standard field_image field):

```
SELECT fm.uri
FROM {file_managed} fm
INNER JOIN field_data_field_image fi ON fi.entity_type = 'node' AND fi.bundle = 'article' AND fi.deleted = 0 AND fi.field_image_fid = fm.fid
WHERE fi.entity_id = <nid>
```

Where `<nid>` is the node ID. From there you'll need to perform whatever logic you need to translate the paths to something useful for your iOS app. Drupal uses [`file_create_url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_create_url/7) to perform the same task, so that's your best starting point for inspiration. Depending on your setup you may well get away with just doing a string replace on `public://` to `http://example.com/sites/default/files/`.

Long term, you might want to look at adding the [Services module](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) and consuming the REST API in your app, instead of querying the DB directly. It'll take a lot of the strain of preparing Drupal's data out of your hands so you can just deal with what you need.

Comment: Hi @Clive! Thanks for your response. I ended up installing the Services module to my Drupal site like you suggested, creating a views endpoint (with JSON output), and accessing the image URL that way :) Works like a charm.